# How to detect if website is viewed by google cache/crawler

Tags: javascript, google-crawlers

My question title might be wrong but that is what I can figure out right now.
I opened my webpage in cached version of google:
cache:mywebsiteurl.com

It shows snapshot of my webpage as taken by google crawler while indexing (correct me if I am wrong).
My website does not load properly in this snapshot while loading it in google cache version it shows correct UI for few seconds and then go to 404 route of my website. After searching I get to understand that it is because javascript is not loaded which I included in scripts. Therefore when scripts have to be accessed page fails. Therefore I want to show my page without scripts when google crawler checks my page. Is there a way by which I can add a condition that scripts can be ignored when google is taking snapshot of webpage?

My website is built with reactjs and we are using server side rendering.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Taking a look at Google's docs, looks like by adding a "user-agent" to a robot.txt file in your app could specify what pages you want Google's crawlers to go to.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943

Comment: @StrayAnt why don't you add an answer?

Comment: @jannis the answer is that link.... I can't explain it any better than Google.

Comment: @StrayAnt You could summarize the information in the linked resource and post it as answer.